# What is the reason for having function for fetchRequest on an NSManagedObject class

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data, swiftui

On my app, I'm using manual code gen for one of my Core Data entities. When doing so, I had Xcode generate the class and extension files for me in which one of them had the following code block:

```
@nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Sensor> {
    return NSFetchRequest<Sensor>(entityName: "Sensor")
}
```

I can remove this and everything seems to work fine but I read in places that it's used by Core Data in order to function properly. So my question is: **What exactly is this block doing and is it required for proper functionality to the entity?**

Comment: It's just a convenience function for constructing a fetchRequest and nothing more (although I don't remember if any of Apple's templates are making use of it). It's definitely not required (if it _was_ required you would see compilation errors).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a convenience factory method to be able to create a fetch request type safe with

```
let request : NSFetchRequest<Sensor> = Sensor.fetchRequest()
```

along the lines of the convenience initializer syntax

```
let sensor = Sensor(context: context)
```

It's not required.

Comment: I think that makes sense... so instead of `NSFetchRequest<Sensor>(entityName: "Sensor")` I can just do `Sensor.fetchRequest()` ?